# How to give command to print on IP printer?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to print from IP printer. I have a url of printer. Is it possible to print without device install on my local machine. We have not set up cups server. We only have IP of printer and it is in our Intranet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print to an IP printer without the driver if you want to print raw text. I'm not sure if it will be possible for documents such as pdf / word etc.

To print raw text you would need to specify IP and Port - default port is usually 9000. You can test with something like telnet to send text to the socket. Depending on the printer used you would also have to look at the raw commands for if you wanted to cut text or change font sizes for example.